# How to add class to last tr of the table using jquery

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

The code have to work with ie so :last is not an option

```
<table class="ms-main" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" height="100%">
<tr>..</tr>
<tr>..</tr>
<tr>..</tr>
<tr class=add this value including class=>..</tr>
</table>
```

Thank you in advance

EDIT1:

How about if the source file is this?

```
<table class="ms-main" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%" height="100%">
<tr>..</tr>
<tr>..</tr>
<tr>..</tr>
<tr class=add this value including class=>**<table>more nested tables here</table>**</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:last` does work in IE.

jQuery implements this manually, it has no relation to the css selectors supported by the browser.

```
$('.ms-main tr:last').addClass('name-of-class');
```

[Here's a nice article](http://blog.bigbinary.com/2010/02/15/how-jquery-selects-elements-using-sizzle.html) on jQuery's implementation of the sizzle selector and use of `querySelectorAll`

As for your edit, you may want to use `>` to denote that the `tr` should be an immediate child, and not a more distant descendant.

```
$('.ms-main > tr:last')
```

Look out for `tbody`, though.

Answer (score 0):

`$('table tr').last().addClass('myClass');`

Selector `:last-child` is not supported in IE 6-8, use method last() to find last element in DOM

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
   $("table tr:last").addClass("lastOne");
</script>
```